# Why my arrow function with object filter does not work

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, array-filter

Can anybody please tell me why my arrow function that filters an array of object does not work. The snippet is shortened but the idea is to combine two key values from one object and match it with another key value from another object.

```
 const fNFS_S = [{"Seq":0,"KeyReg":"020620222022000258","TaxId":"06.865.436/0001-20","KeyId":"86520","NfDate":"02/06/2022","RegDate":"02/07/2022","NfNum":"20220002","NfMod":"2022","NfVal":"200,00","IRRF":"0,00","RetISS":"0,00","RetPIS":"0,00","RetCOF":"0,00","RetCSLL":"0,00","NumFat":"2022000258","PgFat":"1"}];

 const fData = [{"docnum":"2022000258","vendor":"4.1.1.01.0003","docdate":"02/06/2022","expirydate":"02/07/2022","paymentcondition":"","category":"1.1.2.04.0001","itemdescrip":"CV:Valor ref.a servicos de mao de obra de industrializ. de moveis cfe nf nº 2022000258","itemvalue":"200,00","message":""}];

 var cnpjcheck = fData[0]['docdate'].replaceAll('/','') + fData[0]['docnum'];

 var keyregcheck = fNFS_S[0]['KeyReg'];

 var dupl = fNFS_S.filter(o => o.KeyReg === cnpjcheck); //this never get matched
```

I have even tried to debug their code units but it seem that they are really the same

```
 console.log(cnpjcheck === keyregcheck);

 for (var i = 0; i < cnpjcheck.length; i++) {
            console.log(cnpjcheck.codePointAt(i), keyregcheck.codePointAt(i));
          }
```

```js
const fNFS_S = [{"Seq":0,"KeyReg":"020620222022000258","TaxId":"06.865.436/0001-20","KeyId":"86520","NfDate":"02/06/2022","RegDate":"02/07/2022","NfNum":"20220002","NfMod":"2022","NfVal":"200,00","IRRF":"0,00","RetISS":"0,00","RetPIS":"0,00","RetCOF":"0,00","RetCSLL":"0,00","NumFat":"2022000258","PgFat":"1"}];

 const fData = [{"docnum":"2022000258","vendor":"4.1.1.01.0003","docdate":"02/06/2022","expirydate":"02/07/2022","paymentcondition":"","category":"1.1.2.04.0001","itemdescrip":"CV:Valor ref.a servicos de mao de obra de industrializ. de moveis cfe nf nº 2022000258","itemvalue":"200,00","message":""}];

var cnpjcheck = fData[0]['docdate'].replaceAll('/','') + fData[0]['docnum'];

var keyregcheck = fNFS_S[0]['KeyReg'];

console.log(cnpjcheck === keyregcheck);

for (var i = 0; i < cnpjcheck.length; i++) {
                console.log(cnpjcheck.codePointAt(i), keyregcheck.codePointAt(i));
              }  

var dupl = fNFS_S.filter(o => o.KeyReg === cnpjcheck);
console.log(dupl);
```

Edit: It does work here but does NOT work in my Google AppScript snippet

If you see my debugger the last value is the combined one trying to be matched with the second (KeyReg). One thing that caught my attention is that it's " has gone to another line. I have tried to trim() and normalize() it but nothing changed.

The result is it gets past and goes into a loop as it does not find it

[image: Debugger Watch]

Comment: What result do you actually want out of this? If you just want to check if the values match, use `if (keyregcheck === cnpjcheck)`. [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) is used to transform one array to another with fewer elements. There are no arrays in your code

Comment: As I said it's a shortened version so I have many obj inside the array, so I think it's best to look to the match this way.

Comment: No repro ~ https://jsfiddle.net/pt4kxowv/

Comment: That's a bummer cuz it's not working in my AppScript snippet. Any idea on how to debug that?

Comment: _"It does work here"_... If you cannot provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), then this question is un-answerable

Comment: About `why my arrow function that filters an object does not work.` and `Edit: It does work here but does NOT work in my Google AppScript snippet`, in your current situation, can I ask you whether V8 runtime is enabled with the script editor of Google Apps Script? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime#enabling_the_v8_runtime) If V8 runtime is disabled, the arrow function cannot be used. So, I'm worried about this.

Comment: @Tanaike yes v8 is enabled. I have added a picture that shows the values being debugged

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I confirmed that your script editor enables V8 runtime. When I tested your showing script (bottom script) at the script editor of Google Apps Script, it was the same result as Javascript in your question. So, in order to correctly replicate your current situation, can you provide your current result values of Google Apps Script?

Comment: @Tanaike If I understood your request, I have updated the post with my Debugger Watcher

Comment: Thank you for replying. From `If I understood your request, I have updated the post with my Debugger Watcher`, I couldn't understand your current values. I think that this is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for my poor skill again. But, I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand your current value, I would like to compare it with the result from Javascript.  I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor skill.

Answer (score -1):

This is specified because its fNFS_S variable is an object not an array, so it doesn't have a filter method.
try to declare it like this:

```
fNFS_S = [{"KeyReg":"020620222022000258"}];
```

Comment: Sorry, I have now added my full object which is indeed object inside an array. Either way it does not work yet

Answer (score -1):

'fNFS_S' must be an object(s) inside an array.
like this:
const fNFS_S = [{"KeyReg":"020620222022000258"}];

Comment: Sorry, I have now added my full object which is indeed object inside an array.